# Improve dd restore speed

Tags: linux, dd, lvm

Just now after waiting about **33 hours** I finished restoring hard disk `dev.pm.m3` resided on the LVM partition from previosly created zipped dump `5_dev.pm.m3_2012-11-03.gz`.

Here is its status:

```
gzip -dc /servdata/backup/trex/5_dev.pm.m3_2012-11-03.gz | dd of=/dev/trex/dev.pm.m3
.................
.................
134217728+0 records in
134217728+0 records out
68719476736 bytes (69 GB) copied, 120513 s, 570 kB/s
```

How I can improve copying speed (570 kB/s is very slow). May be I need to use another tool for working with LVM?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It could be that `gzip` is slowing down the thing.

Comment: If you have a really weak CPU: Yes, gzip could slow things down. But I suspect most of those 33 hours are not used on decompressing 69GB. The overhead of 134217728 (512 bytes sized) transactions is a much more likely cause.

Answer (score 9):

The default blocksize of dd is 512 bytes read or written. You can increase it to 1 megabyte for example, to improve writing speed:

> $ gzip -dc /servdata/backup/trex/5_dev.pm.m3_2012-11-03.gz | dd bs=1M of=/dev/trex/dev.pm.m3

See [man dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) for further info.

Comment: The blocksize is definitely the issue here.

Comment: Is `dd` needed at all in this case? I recall doing simple zcat to a filesystem (e.g. `gzip -dc /servdata/backup/trex/5_dev.pm.m3_2012-11-03.gz > /dev/trex/dev.pm.m3`)

Comment: I should work without `dd`, but I don't know how fast or slow it would be.